# zConvert an HTML file into a Python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

```
<html>
<p class="rientro"><b>Abbagliato</b> (l’), sanese, uomo goloso che consu</p>
<p class="rientro">mò il suo in crapule. Inf. XXIX, 132.</p>
<p class="rientro"><b>Abbajare</b>, per dimostrar gridando. Inf. VII, 43.</p>
<p class="rientro"><b>Abbandonare</b>, per lasciare una impresa difficile: Par. 
XVIII, 9.</p>
.
.
.
</html>
```

I have a 'dictionary' in the above format and would like to convert the HTML text into a Python dictionary e.g abbagliato: sanese, uomo goloso che…, abbajare: per dimostrar etc.
I am even unable to read the html file as text using Python at the minute. Can someone give me some ideas how to approach this, please ( I want to make a searchable dictionary to allow me to read Dante's inferno in Italian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Python 3 code will parse a HTML file ("dict.html") and return a dict object contain words and their definitions. This code assumes the HTML file is formatted as in your example, i.e. `<p><b>Some word</b>Word definition</p>`.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

dictionary = {}

# Custom html parser which will add word and definition pairs
# to the dict 'dictionary'
class html_to_dict_parser(HTMLParser):
  def __init__(self):
    HTMLParser.__init__(self)
    # These variables will tell the parser what data it's reading at the moment
    self.in_word_label = False
    self.in_definition = False
    self.has_definition = False

  # Called everytime the parser encounters a new tag
  # e.g. <html> or <p>
  def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if tag == 'b':
      self.in_word_label  = True
    elif tag == 'p':
      self.in_definition  = True

  # Similar to above
  def handle_endtag(self, tag):
    if tag == 'b':
      self.in_word_label = False
    elif tag == 'p':
      self.in_definition  = False

  # Called when the parser encounters the contents of a tag
  # e.g. 'Some word' in '<p>Some word</p>
  def handle_data(self, data):
    if self.in_word_label:
      # Inside a <b> tag
      self.latest_word = data.lower()
      self.has_definition = True
    elif self.in_definition and self.has_definition:
      # Inside a <p> tag which also contained a <b> tag
      dictionary[ self.latest_word ] = data
      self.has_definition = False

# Run the parser!
parser = html_to_dict_parser()
with open('dict.html') as html_file:
  parser.feed(html_file.read())

parser.close()
print(dictionary)
```

Example output of the dict created using your html above:

```
{'abbajare': ', per dimostrar gridando. Inf. VII, 43.', 'abbandonare': ', per lasciare una impresa difficile: Par.\nXVIII, 9.', 'abbagliato': ' (l’), sanese, uomo goloso che consu'}
```

It should now be fairly easy to search the dict for a word of your choice, for example if you were to pass command arguments to the interpreter (e.g. `$ python3 dict_parser.py abbandonare`) you could extend the program above to search for the words you pass it:

```
import sys

for word in sys.argv[1:]:
  if word in dictionary:
    print(word, ':', dictionary[word])
  else:
    print(word, "not found in dictionary.")
```

**Further info:**

Docs for the HTML parser module: http://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

Comment: I am hesitant to prevail upon you again. Thank you for the solution which works, as you say, for the snippet that I supplied. When I use the larger file I get an error: UnicodeDecode Error: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 480: ordinal not in range(128). What should I be looking for to cause this problem?

Comment: The offending line appears to be or at least adding this line to the previous provokes the error: <p class="rientro"><b>Abbaglia</b>. Di fuor dorate son, sì ch’egli abbaglia; 
cioè abbagliano. Inf. XXIII, 64. Il verbo singolare invece del plurale; quando 
non fosse una ellissi, che si dovesse supplir così: quella doratura, quel color 
d’oro abbaglia.</p>

Comment: Is the problem the Italian accents which I guess are unicode characters? If so, can one get around this? Certainly deleting everything from the first comma in the phrase above solves the issue for this entry( also makes it useless, but thats beside the point at this stage) Thank you once again

Comment: Try setting the file encoding to utf-8 when you open dict.html, i.e.: `open('dict.html', encoding='utf-8')`. If that still fails try running the program with the following command: `$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python3 dict_parser.py`.

Comment: Thank you. Will try your suggestion